# Dirichlet series associated to smallest prime factors

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

If we denote by $p_1(n)$ the smallest prime factor of $n$, has the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{p_1(n)}{n^s}$$already been studied? What is known about its analytic continuation?

Comment: What is the point of defining this Dirichlet series? What does it give us?

Comment: The smallest prime factor of every even number is $2.$

Comment: @6005: what's the problem in defining it? It is just a generating function for the sequence $(p_1(n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Somehow it contains information about it

Comment: @user1749368 There's no "problem" in defining it, but if you can't extract the information in a meaningful way, or show some relevant properties of this generating function, then likely it hasn't been studied because there's no point in studying it.

Comment: $S>\displaystyle\sum_pp^{1-s},$ which is known to diverge for $s\le2.$

Comment: @Lucian: yes, the half-plane of (absolute) convergence is $\sigma>2$. Moreover, the following identity holds: $$S=\zeta(s)\sum_p\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}\prod_{p'<p}\left(1-\frac{1}{(p')^s}\right).$$ From this relation you deduce the same result by asymptotic comparison test. My question was about what is known on the analytic continuation beyond the line $\sigma=2$. Notice that by Landau Theorem $s=2$ is necessarily a singularity.

Comment: @6005: for example, by studying the singularity $s=2$ and applying Tauberian results, you find the first term of the (already known) asymptotic expansion for $\sum_{n\leq x}p_1(n)$.

Comment: @user1749368 I agree. I get $\sum_{p_1(n) = p} n^{-s} = \zeta(s) p^{-s}\underbrace{\prod_{q < p} (1-q^{-s})}_{K_p(s)}$ so that $P_1(s) = \sum_n p_1(n)  n^{-s} = \sum_p p \sum_{p_1(n) = p} n^{-s}  = \zeta(s) \sum_p K_p(s)p^{1-s}$.

Comment: Finding its domain of convergence and meromorphy (under the Riemann hypothesis) is not so easy, it relies on $\log K_s(p) = \sum_{q < p} \log (1-q^{-s}) =  -\sum_{q < p} q^{-s} + \underbrace{\mathcal{O}(\sum_{q < p} |q^{-2s}|}_{= \mathcal{O}(1) \ \text{ when } Re(s) > 1/2+\epsilon})$ $ = -\sum_{n =2}^p 
\frac{n^{-s}}{\ln n} + \mathcal{O}(\sum_{n=1}^p|n^{-2s}|+|n^{-s-1+\sigma_0+\epsilon}|) $ where $\zeta(s)$ has no zero for $Re(s) > \sigma_0$